# Why does Panasonic/Lumix use Micro Four Thirds?

Tags: dslr, panasonic-lumix

Simple question really. Why do these cameras use micro four thirds?

Comment: Have you checked the web sites of Panasonic and read the Wikipedia entry for Micro Four Thirds? What specific kind of reason do you need for Panasonic using a standard they have agreed on with several other manufacturers?

Comment: I want to learn reasons they use Micro Four. Why and history why and how.

Comment: The same reason Olympus uses micro four thirds :-)

Comment: @EricShain Not necessarily. One of them might use the standard mostly because the other does, rather than for the reasons the other chose it.

Comment: @MichaelC They developed the standard together.

Comment: Well, sort of. They developed the Micro Four-Thirds system as an evolution of the Four-Thirds system together. Olympus and Kodak developed the Four-Thirds System.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About Four Thirds system:

Before wide screen (16:9) monitors and televisions were popular, 4:3 monitors/televisions as the norm; so I guess it seems normal to have sensors which are compatible.

The Micro Four Thirds system has a shorter registration distance (a/k/a flange focal distance), to reduce the weight (and price) for cameras, but uses the same sensor size and 4:3 aspect ratio.

Wikipedia:

[Wikipedia: Four Thirds system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Thirds_system)

[Wikipedia: Micro Four Thirds system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_Four_Thirds_system)

Comment: 4/3 refers to the sensor size, as well as the aspect ratio. Micro 4/3 is the same size sensor, it is smaller because it is mirrorless.

Comment: @vclaw It would probably be more precise to say, "Micro 4/3 is the same size sensor. The registration distance (flange focal distance) being shorter requires it to be mirrorless." In other words, Micro Four-Thirds is mirrorless because the shorter FFD does not leave room for a mirror, not the other way around. One *could* have a mirrorless system with a FFD long enough to allow a mirror, but one can not have an SLR with a FFD too short for a mirror.

Comment: Four Thirds is not really compatible or interchangeable with Micro Four Thirds. Micro Four Thirds is mirrorless, Four Thirds is DSLR. Micro Four Thirds lenses can NOT be used on a Four-Thirds camera body. Four Thirds lenses can be used on a Micro Four Thirds camera body if you use an adapter.

Comment: @MikeSowsun True ... I meant with compatible the output ratio is compatible (meaning that no conversion is needed from 16:9 to 4:3 of otherwise when using either normal four thirds or micro four thirds).